# Can I use Cognito for users authentication in an app hosted in DigitalOcean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, digital-ocean

I have an app hosted in a DigitalOcean server that is only used by me. Now I would like to give access to some friends, so I need users authentication management.

I have read AWS Cognito is a good option however it is not clear to me if it is possible to implement only AWS Cognito to work in joint cooperation with other services or if I need to migrate all to AWS to be able to use Cognito. I’ve been looking for tutorials but all talk about using Cognito in addition to other AWS services.

The point is that I’m using a Postgres DB and looking at AWS prices it is expensive to me to migrate to AWS. In case it is to do what I would like, I really appreciate recommended lectures.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> I need users authentication management. 
>   I have read AWS Cognito is a good option

Indeed the AWS Cognito is a good option for user authentication and authorization. If you have a web app, you may as well check out the [AWS amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/ui) framework for easier onboarding.

> if it is possible to implement only AWS Cognito

You don't need to use any other AWS services or migrate your infrastructure. Your application can use Cognito indepently.

You can use Cognito even as a pure [OAuth 2.0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html) based authentication and authorization service if you want to keep really independent.

> all talk about using Cognito in addition to other AWS services

Cognito can provide its users session (temporary) aws credentials to use AWS services. You don't have to use the feature if you don't need to.